# Unit Testing Jest Node Fetch

Tags: node.js, jestjs, fetch

I'm trying to test a class method's return value.

This class method fetches from an API.

When testing I decide to mock the fetch request so I don't hit the network.

How would I go about doing this?? Preferably without an external library.

**ClassA**

```js
class ClassA {
    constructor() {
    }

    fetchSpotDate(pair) {
        const url = 'url';
        const query = 'query';
        fetch(url + query)
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(json => new Date(json.settlement_date + "Z"))
            .catch(e => {
                log.error(e)
            });
    }
}
```

**Test**

```js
it('should return correct date object format',  async () => {
        const mockSuccessResponse = {
          foo: 'bar', 
          settlement_date: '2020-06-29T00:00:00' 
        };
        const mockJsonPromise = Promise.resolve(mockSuccessResponse);
        const mockFetchPromise = Promise.resolve({json: () => mockJsonPromise})
        const expectedReturn = new Date("2020-06-29T00:00:00Z")
        global.fetch = jest.fn(() => mockFetchPromise);
        const classA = new ClassA();

        const result = await classA.fetchSpotDate('EURUSD')
        expect(???result Promise value???).toEqual(expectedReturn)
    });
```